# SQL items Smart rating

Tags: sql, t-sql, rating

trying to get normal price rating 
using

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY [price] asc) as [Rating]
```

[image: Result that I have now]

But I need rating like:

[image]

I know thats suppose to be easy - but google didnt gave me any idea.
Need  you help

Answer (score 1):

Take `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`. Then it should work:

```
DENSE_RANK OVER(PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY [price] ASC) AS [Rating]
```